# How can i put different tittle icons depending on the day?

Tags: html, css

I´m doing a calendar and i want to show on the tittle icon the number of the day, something similar to what whatsapp web does (it shows the number of unread messages you have). If someone knows how to do it i´d deeply aprecciate it

Comment: I think you could write a function or use an API.

Comment: You should use Javascript. For example the function getDate().

Comment: Take a minute and read over stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. After you read that over, come back and update your question with more details and code that you are using that is not working. As it stands currently you are basically asking to have the work done for you as opposed to asking for help solving a specific problem you are having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best practice is to use JavaScript and dynamically render the icons.

But if you haven't learned JavaScript yet you can do it CSS only but it is a little bit tricky. You need to use nth-child CSS pseudo-class and then use ::before or ::after tags to put the icons or emojis for being easier.

```
.day:nth-child(7n+1)::before {
    content: 'monday';
}
```

:nth-child(7n +1) means every 7 element the first index. you can go up to 7 so you can cover every day in the week